# ORMLite QueryBuilder.orderByRaw(String, SelectArg) ignores SelectArg on QueryBuilder.queryRaw()

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I have a fresh `QueryBuilder<Card, Integer>`, and I want to `orderByRaw` using a `SelectArg`.

```java
//String column is coming from unknown source
SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg(SqlType.STRING, column);
qBuilder.selectColumns(column).groupBy(column).orderByRaw("? IS NULL ASC", selectArg);
```

After this I want to get the `qBuilder.queryRaw()`. And something really strange happens. The raw statement returned by `qBuilder` is this:

```sql
SELECT `occupation` FROM `card` GROUP BY `occupation` ORDER BY ? IS NULL ASC
```

The `?` is not replaced with what should be `occupation` here, and as expected, nulls appear first in the ordering of the objects.

Although, if doing this:

```java
qBuilder.selectColumns(column).groupBy(column).orderByRaw(column + " IS NULL ASC");
```

ordering works as expected (again using `qBuilder.queryRaw()`), the nulls go last, and everything is ordered by `occupation` ascending.

**Debugging**

```java
protected abstract void appendStatementEnd(StringBuilder sb, List<ArgumentHolder> argList) throws SQLException;
```

The above method will add `SelectArgs` in the argList but then, the `queryRaw()` is called with just the `preparedStamenteString()` and not any `String... arguments`, which is natural since I called it like this in the first place using `qBuilder.queryRaw()`, resulting in calling the method below:

```java
public GenericRawResults<String[]> queryRaw() throws SQLException {
    return dao.queryRaw(prepareStatementString());
}
```

How can I use `orderByRaw` without the fear of letting a possible injection happen?

Comment: Interesting.  Can you reproduce this in a unit test?

Comment: Yes. I was able to reproduce it in a JUnit. Project here: https://github.com/gogos-venge/ORMlite_JUnit

Comment: Can you modify your test to show _data_ instead of just query form?  Insert a could of the `TestObject` with and without `null` values.  What is expected from them?  I've copied your test into my master but I can't figure out what the proper results should be @verge.

Comment: Yes. I just pushed a new test with some mockup. 5 words and 5 null values. Using `orderByRaw("? IS NULL ASC", selectArg)` gives a result with the null value first, while `orderByRaw("testColumn IS NULL ASC")` gives a result with the null values last. `orderByRaw("testColumn IS NULL DESC")` will give a result with the null value being first.

Comment: I have made some changes for extra clarity: appendList is now implodeList and also I included a simple select query to show database contents in ormlite.Logger.info. Please consider cloning again!

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think this is a bug @venge.  Your test validates the query string but the expansion of `?` into the string `"testColumn"` happens when the query is executed so it won't be expanded there.  You can turn on logging to see that the right query is being run.  If it wasn't then we'd see problems about no column name `?` or no argument to `?` specified.

> 2019-11-01 18:15:16,761 [TRACE] BaseMappedStatement prepared statement arguments: [testColumn]
>   2019-11-01 18:15:16,781 [DEBUG] StatementExecutor query of 'SELECT `testColumn` FROM `testobject` GROUP BY `testColumn` ORDER BY ? IS NULL ASC ' returned 4 results

I think the problem here is that `ORDER BY ... IN NULL ASC`.  In reading the docs about using NULL there, I'm confused about what it should do.  `ASC` or `DESC` doesn't seem to affect the sort order in my tests.

Comment: `ORDER BY ... IS NULL ASC` should return a result with the null values being last in the sorting order, while `ORDER BY ... IS NULL DESC` should bring the null values first in the sorting order. Rest of the values seem to be unaffected. I confirmed it both in an SQLite editor and the mockup data of the JUnit test I just pushed.

Comment: As far as the column name being `?` in the `ORDER BY` clause, it seems perfectly valid. `?` being a joker character I assume. I just did a `SELECT` in an SQLite editor: `SELECT address FROM card GROUP BY address ORDER BY ? IS NULL ASC` and it didn't complain.